# Create New PHP Project in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno

I want to create a new PHP Project in Eclipse but I found no `PHP Project` Option after clicking `File > New >`.

[image]

What should I do to create a new PHP Project in Eclipse Juno?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) package for Eclipse.  From the link given:

> In Eclipse, click Help -> Install New Software and work with *: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.5

Once you have installed the plugin, you should be able to create a PHP project.

Comment: @Yahweh Please review the answers given to your question

Answer (score 1):

Do you install PDT? See this: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Answer (score 1):

You probably are on Java Perspective, whre "new PHP project" item isn't contributed. Use File -> New -> Other (ctrl+n shortcut) and select php project from list.

Off course Eclipse PDT have to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, June 2018, the URL to download the plugin is:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/5.3

This will become outdated over time so anyone reading this post in the future should just check...

https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

...for the current version.